# Нужно вывести количество книг от каждого издательства

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такая таблица: в колонке `id_publishing` издательства, в `id_book` книги которые они издавали.

То есть у первого издательства 4 книги (3, 8, 5, 7), у второго 2 книги (2,1) и так далее.

Нужно вывести номера всех издательств и количество книг, которое каждое из них издало.

Для одного конкретного я считаю вот так

```sql
SELECT
    publishing_book.id_publishing,
    COUNT(publishing_book.id) as count_book
FROM
    publishing_book
WHERE
    publishing_book.id_publishing = 1
;
```

[image: Таблица]

Comment: идете на sqlfiddle, создаете тестовую базу. пробуете что-то сделать. если не получится, публикуете ссылку и наилучший на ваш взгляд запрос в вопросе. Мы пробуем помочь

Comment: @splash58 Базу я уже создал на phpmyadmin, пытался делать через COUNT, но не могу сообразить как подсчитать количество книг ДЛЯ КАЖДОГО издательства. Для одного я считаю вот так SELECT publishing_book.id_publishing, COUNT(publishing_book.id) as count_book FROM publishing_book WHERE publishing_book.id_publishing = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, ознакомьтесь, мб поможет. https://fortress-design.com/count-records-mysql/

Вообще нужно писать в вопросе ваш опыт/попытки решения этой задачи, иначе это выглядит как задание.

Comment: Спасибо, добавил пример как я считал для одного конкретного издательства в пост. Ваша ссылка помогла все сделать)

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так вывести, если еще актуально

```
SELECT
    id_publishing,
    COUNT(id_book) books_count
FROM
    publishing_book
GROUP BY
    id_publishing;
```